# Multiple level nested routing does not work in react app

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I implemented the multiple level nested routing in my application but it doesn't work. I have created a sample code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-babbage-n4ncg?file=/src/Page1.js

there If I try to navigate from the home page to Page1 then it simply does not render the page even though the URL has changed.

Many thanks

Comment: 1. `<Route exact path="/home">` --> `<Route path="/home">`; 2. inside `Home`, `<Link to="/page1">` --> `<Link to="/home/page1">` and 3. `<Route exact path="/page1">` --> `<Route exact path="/home/page1">`

Comment: Do you ***want*** "/page1" and "/page2" to be nested under the "/home" path,i.e. like "/home/page1"? or do you just want to link to them from the home page? Please check this [official nested doc and example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting). Also, please include the relevant code example in your question.

Comment: Yes I want them to be nested under the "/home"

Comment: Read and follow the doc I linked, it shows how to create the nested sub-routes. If you need further help, just let us know.

Comment: [Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-leftpad-9fyt4?file=/src/App.js:303-323)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove **exact** prop from your parent route, which will prevent render nested routes since they are not exactly matched to the first route.

**From**

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <h1>App component</h1>
        <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
        **<Route exact path="/home">**
          <Home />
        </Route>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

**To**

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <h1>App component</h1>
        <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
        **<Route path="/home">**
          <Home />
        </Route>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```